# session in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am facing a problem.

I maintain a session after login like `session["UserID"]` and every page is locked with this session like

```
if(session["UserID"] == "")
{
Response.redirect("./loginpage.aspx");
}
else
{
// page working code
}
```

Problem is that i am saving the data then redirect the page after saving session was automatically clear and the page is redirect to login page.

in web config file i write this line

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"  timeout="60">
```

how i solved this problem to stay in session state on save data and redirecting the same page.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to ask here? What seems to be the problem? Especially stating, that you've solved something... Is there actually any problem at all?

Comment: Are you using the standard Forms Authentication form ASP .Net (enabled by authentication mode="Forms" in web.config) or you have your own custom authentication system?

Comment: Could you provide us some details about how and when "session was automatically clear"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Session.Abandon() call before redirecting to loginpage.aspx